# Interleaving WPF Boxes to Make Aperture

Tags: wpf, z-index, clip

I'm trying to make a camera aperture animation in WPF.  I've got it mostly working, but the problem I am running into is a z-order one.

There are 8 blades.  1 under 2, 2 under 3, etc...

But blade 8 should be on top of 7, but under 1.  I tried to solve this with clipping, but I couldn't get it to work.  The following image shows what I'm trying to do.

Is there a way to get render-transformed controls to be clipped by sibling render-transformed controls?  I'd like to just tell blade 8 it is clipped by blade 1.

[image]

Comment: You might be able to do this using a `Viewport3D`, but you would have to convert everything in to 3 dimensional space to get the correct overlap.  It might be overkill for what you are trying to do though. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747437(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I had considered that.  Was hoping there was a simpler option.

Comment: I have re-worked this to use non-overlapping triangles.  Still interested in a solution though.